# Flink State | check last data is the first data

Tags: apache-flink

How do I check last data is the first data use Flink State

```
  override def flatMap(value: myData, out: Collector[(String, Double, Double)]): Unit = {
    val lastValue = lastValueState.value()
    val diff = (value.item_data-lastValue).abs
    if (diff > Threshold)
      out.collect((value.item_id,lastValue,value.item_data))

    lastValueState.update(value.item_data)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValueState#value()` returns null if nothing has been previously stored for the key that is currently in scope (the key corresponding to the current `value` being processed).